# How to update a send definition using exact target's api

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, soap, php

I would like to update the list id associated to a send definition. How do we go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the list ID in this sample packet:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">qnnwntr3mptvnwa5e3rku6m3</fueloauth>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <Objects xsi:type="EmailSendDefinition">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <CustomerKey>Test_EmailSendDefinition_CustKey</CustomerKey>
        <Name>ET EmailSendDefinition Daily demo to Update</Name>
        <SendClassification>
           <PartnerKey/>
           <CustomerKey>Test_SendClassification_CustKey</CustomerKey>
           <SenderProfile>
              <CustomerKey>Test_SenderProfile_CustKey</CustomerKey>
           </SenderProfile>
        </SendClassification>
        <!--Specifies audience associated with an email send definition.-->
        <SendDefinitionList>
           <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
           <CustomerKey>Test_EmailSendDefinition_CustKey</CustomerKey>
           <List>
              <ID>12306</ID>
              <CustomerKey>Test_List_CustKey</CustomerKey>
           </List>
           <DataSourceTypeID>List</DataSourceTypeID>
        </SendDefinitionList>
        <Email>
           <ID>8544</ID>
           <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        </Email>
     </Objects>
  </UpdateRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Anyway to get php code for this?

Comment: @Jimmy Still you are looking for PHP code or you got it?